# Coldfusion REST service not found error

Tags: rest, coldfusion

I have a problem with calling REST servise. It returns NOT FOUND error always.

REST service is registered in CF administrator:

- Root path: D:\projects\testcf11\restfolder
- Host: testcf11.localhost
- Service Mapping: testrest

In /restfolder is one cf component:

```
<cfcomponent rest="true" restpath="Customers">
<cffunction name="getCustomer" restpath="{customerID}" access="remote" returntype="String" httpmethod="GET">
    <cfargument name="customerID" required="true" restargsource="Path" type="numeric">
    <cfset ret = "Customer ID: " & arguments.customerID>
    <cfreturn ret>
</cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```

I try it with that code:

```
<cfhttp url="http://testcf11.localhost/rest/testrest/Customers/1" method="get">
</cfhttp>
<cfdump var="#cfhttp#" />
```

Softwer: Windows 8.1, Apache 2.4, CF 11 Developer Edition

Thanks for any idea

EDIT1:

I have an entry in hosts file.

```
127.0.0.1 testcf11.localhost
```

Comment: It seems like the problem is associated with host name. Have you made an entry in your `hosts` file for `testcf11.localhost`? Try adding it and it may solve the problem.

Comment: Go to `Administrator` and refresh the rest service you created. And then try again.

Comment: rest service is refreshed. still not found error

Comment: Try calling the url directly from browser. See what it shows.

Comment: It shows not found page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in port. If the rest URL contains port 8500, everything is OK.

Comment: I forgot you are using Apache, the in built server. If you use IIS then 80 is the default port and you don't need to add the port number to the url. In my case it was IIS, so it worked.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the problem is associated with `hostname`. Have you made an entry in your `hosts` file for `testcf11.localhost`? Try adding it and it may solve the problem. The `hosts` file is located inside `%windir%\system32\drivers\etc`. Edit the file and make an entry similar to this.

```
127.0.0.1    testcf11.localhost
```

After making the entry you may need to restart your system.
I checked it on my system and it works.

Comment: Yes, I have an entry in hosts file.